# Nginx Server Block Config

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, virtualhost

I'm having a problem with my nginx configuration. I have several virtual hosts on the same server. However, I'm attempting to add another virtual host, this one being an SSL website. The website returned for the domain is not the correct one.

If I change from listen 443 to listen 80, the correct website is restored. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Below is the configuration for the vhost in question.

vhost-config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name *.website.com;

    root /var/www/vhost/www.website.com/public_html/httpdocs/;
    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.website.com/website.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.website.com/website.com.key;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI    $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI   $document_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT  $document_root;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR    $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT    $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR    $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT    $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME    $server_name;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING   $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }

}
```

nginx.config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

##
# Size Limit
##

client_max_body_size 2M;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Do you have a default vhost also listening for SSL ? What do you mean by "the website returned for the domain is not the correct one" ? Could you clarify with actual observed behaviour ? Is there anything else running on port 443 on the machine ?

Comment: There is no default vhost listening on SSL. The website that's returned is the last of the websites in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/* folder in Ascii order. Nothing else running on port 443.

Comment: What's the overall count of server names handled by included configurations ?

Comment: 14 overall server names handled. If I change the listening port to 80 in the server directive, the website loads just fine.

Comment: Do you test this behaviour with curl or something not using cached response headers ? What version of nginx are you running ? Put your log in debug mode and post it with the curl request & response.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more then one virtual host with SSL enabled? I think they both are the same IP and you are trying to check using something that does not support SNI, so domain name is not used to choose correct virtual host.
So please post the whole configuration file and logs. Maybe answer is there.

Comment: Glueon - Thanks for your reply. There actually isn't any other website using 443/SSL. I've also posted the configuration for nginx that each and every vhost use. Thanks.

Comment: Where are the log files and other virtual host configurations?

Comment: Still i see only one server {} directive. Where does the content of the wrong domain come from? I think there are some more virtual hosts declared under /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

Comment: Glueon - There are other vhosts declared, and all are listening on 80. However, anytime one of the vhost configurations are corrupt, the page the default page loads which in this case is the last server name in ascii order in the /etc/nginx/sites-available.